# Bugs in a code snippet

Tags: c

Spot all bugs in the code snippet below

```
uint arr[100]
for (uint i=99; i >=0; i--)
    arr[i] = 0;
```

This is a question for the test, can anybody point me to all bugs in this snippet

Comment: -1: Tests are supposed to test your knowledge on the material taught. Asking here will not benefit you and, most likely, you are not going to get the answers expected from you based on what you have been taught. I suggest reading the relevant chapters of the material you are being tested on.

Answer (score 4):

1. `uint` isn't a type.
2. The first line is missing a semicolon.
3. `i >= 0` is always true.
4. `arr[0U - 1]` is undefined behavior because it access outside the bounds of the arr array.
5. It's not clear that this snippet is running as part of a function. If it is not, then the entire for-loop is a syntax error.

Additionally, if this class is taking place before 1999, then:

1. You can't declare variables in a for loop. Instead, the `uint i` should be declared before the loop.

This code should probably be rewritten as simply:

```
unsigned arr[100] = {0};
```

Comment: I would assume uint is an alias for unsigned int. Not entirely sure if that would be considered a bug or not. Either way I guess it's not declared anywhere.

Comment: @ThunderGr: Because `i` is an unsigned number. And `0U - 1` is a large positive number.

Comment: Possibly the declaration of a variable inside of a for loop could be considered one, if using a pre C99 compiler.

Comment: @ThunderGr when you see 'uint', what else do you think of besides 'unsigned int'. You are right that in this snippet it is not defined but common sense should tell you what it was meant to be.

Comment: +1 for providing a candidate simplified code.

Comment: I deleted my for-fun comments, to avoid confusing people that would like to take this question seriously.

Comment: @chux Providing a candidate simplified code to substitute a snippet given in a test? What is the use of that?

Comment: @ThunderGr seriously?